# The $response were displaying twice after the user inputs their answer

Tags: php

I've been trying to fix my problem for several days now, and I'm hoping someone could give me an advice on how to fix it. I might've had overlooked the code but here's the complete content.

```
<?PHP
    include 'functions/generate_word.php';

    $num_words_generated = isset($_SESSION['num_words_generated']) ? $_SESSION['num_words_generated'] : 0;
    $random_word_jumbled = str_shuffle($currentWord);

    if ($num_words_generated <= 10)
    {
        $_SESSION['num_words_generated'] =+ $num_words_generated;
        $item_num = $_SESSION['num_words_generated'];
```

This is the $response that's been appearing twice.

```
        $response = "<div id = 'output-container'><p>Question #" . $item_num . "<br>Unscramble the word: <strong>" . $random_word_jumbled . "</strong></p></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        $response = "<div id = 'output-container'><p>You have finished the quiz!<br>Go back to <a class = 'button' href = 'home.php'>home page.</a></p></div>";
    }
?>

<div id = "chat-container">
    <?PHP
        // Initialize an empty session variable for storing the chat history
        if (!isset($_SESSION['chat_history']))
        {
            $_SESSION['chat_history'] = array();
        }

        array_push($_SESSION['chat_history'], $response);

        // Loop through the chat history and display each message
        foreach ($_SESSION['chat_history'] as $message)
        {
            if (strpos($message, "input-container") !== false)
            {
                // Display user's message with profile photo on the right side
                echo "<div><img src = 'css/child.png' class = 'pfp-right'>" . $message . "</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                // Display AI's response with profile photo on the left side
                echo "<div><img src = 'css/koala.png' class = 'pfp-left'>" . $message . "</div>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>

<form method = "POST">
    <div id = "input-container">
        <?PHP
            // Disable the input field when the counter has reached its limit
            if ($num_words_generated >= 10)
            {
                echo '<input type = "text" name = "user_input" autocomplete = "off" autofocus disabled>';
                echo '<button type = "submit" name = "submit" disabled>Send</button>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<input type = "text" name = "user_input" autocomplete = "off" autofocus>';
                echo '<button type = "submit" name = "submit">Send</button>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</form>

<?PHP
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

        // Add the user's input to the chat history
        array_push($_SESSION['chat_history'], "<div id = 'input-container'><p>" . $user_input . "</p></div>");

        // Process the user's input and generate a response
        if (strtolower($user_input) == strtolower($lastWord))
        {
            $response = "<div id = 'output-container'><p>Correct!</p></div>";

            if (!isset($_SESSION['score']))
            {
                $_SESSION['score'] = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['score'] += 10;
            }

            $total_score = $_SESSION['score'];

            $response .= "<div id = 'output-container'><p>Score: " . $total_score . "</p></div>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            $response = "<div id = 'output-container'><p>Incorrect. The correct answer is: " . $lastWord . "</p></div>";
        }

        // Add the AI's response to the chat history
        array_push($_SESSION['chat_history'], $response);

        // Redirect to the current page to clear the input field
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        ob_end_flush();
    }
?>
```

Here's the output for reference:
[output reference of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S38WM.png)

I have tried to omit some lines, and revised some, and still outputs the same as the image above.

PS. To anyone who saw my question earlier, I apologize that I've been posting not enough details.

Comment: I don't see any repeated output in your image? Nor is it clear how four questions can show up, given the code.

Comment: It appears that you're adding the new question to `chat_history` before processing the user's answer and adding their response to the previous question to the stack.  Is that what you want?  If not, try moving the form processing block to the top of your script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with what is above and below these lines:

```
        array_push($_SESSION['chat_history'], $response);

        // Loop through the chat history and display each message
        foreach ($_SESSION['chat_history'] as $message)
```

The parts above these lines execute every time.  When they post a response/answer you want it to process that first, then generate a new random scrambled word, but it doesn't.  It executes the random generator first, every time, and then adds that to the chat_history array, before it processes the response.

You probably want to move your $_POST handling to the top of the script and use that to decide whether you are handling a POST first, or generating a new random first.

In other words, when your user clicks submit, that entire script executes again from the top.  It does not "pick up where it left off" (in the middle of the script).